# Unused cable (hot and neutral wire), from one circuit (covered with wire nuts), in same outlet box as a newer outlet on a different circuit...This ok?

Tags: electrical

Found a couple of these in outlet boxes in a bedroom of house. Is that ok to leave this way? Really not wanting to tear out plaster, if possible. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are safely capped off, it's technically fine - though the better option would be to find the **other** end of them and disconnect and cap off there (so it's just a dead wire for possible future use, ideally also labeled as to where it goes) rather than leave it live but unused.

If you are not actually "abandoning" the wire you don't have to remove all accessible parts, much less rip walls open to remove it (which is never required. Removing accessible parts is, **if** abandoning.)

Since there might conceivably be use for the wire in the future, just isolate and label. But definitely better to have it isolated if it's disused.

Comment: Appreciate it. It definitely won't be used by me.......old cloth 2 wire stuff, but has newer looking grounded 14/2 Romex on the outlet, though. I'm gonna try to see where it goes. I've found the circuit it's on, but the same circuit is powering a currently used hallway light and an overhead light in bedroom.

Comment: If you've found the other end of _these_ wires, @Brad, you can disconnect them at the other box and wire nut them there as well. Labels at each end to help someone in the future identify where & why these go will be helpful.